# How to "disable" intercept on a specific call

Tags: angular, httpservice

I have a big app which used until now a single http server to make requests.

In the app.module, I have the following Interceptor :

```
  providers: [
    {
      provide: LocationStrategy,
      useClass: HashLocationStrategy
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: JwtInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: ErrorInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }],
```

The problem is, I need to add a single API call to an endpoint from an external service, and I wish I could boycott this interceptor, only for this API call.

```
getAllCesiumModels(params?: apiModels.GetAllCesiumRequest): Observable<apiModels.GetAllModelsResponse>  {
  return this.httpClient.get<any>(`https://api.cesium.com/v1/assets`, {headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${params.accessToken}` }});
}
```

Is there a way, without changing all the app, to make this get request do not skip the interceptor ?

Thank you

Comment: I don't like those answer, but yes, I will inspire from there thx

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that will work, but you can give it a shot.

```
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  public intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
     return next.handle(request).pipe(
            catchError((err) => {
                if(request.url.indexOf("your web app url")==-1)
                {
                  return EMPTY;
                }
            })
        )
   }
}
```

Comment: yes thx will do something like this

Answer (score 0):

in service class

```
bypassedClient: HttpClient

constructor(
   private handler: HttpBackend
) {
   this.bypassedClient = new HttpClient(handler);
}

makeCall(){
this.bypassedClient.post(this.apiURL + Constant.API.authenticate, params)
.subscribe((res)=> console.log(res))
}
```